# Converting Mysql 5.5 dump to Mysql 5.0

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to convert Mysql 5.5 dump from Mysql 5.0 as one of my client's server mysql cannot be upgraded to more than 5.0 . Could someone provide a way to convert mysql 5.5 dump to 5.0 dump

Comment: You can specify the export format when doing the dump.

Comment: could you just suggest where is this option available in Phpmyadmin

Comment: It shows up for me when I select the advanced export options. It's a dropdown with compatibility settings `NONE / ANSI / DB2 / ...` down to `MYSQL40` (not sure what would happen to 5.0 specific things - if such things exist)

Comment: Error in ZIP archive: File is encrypted, which is not supported from this class. This is the error that I am getting after method suggested by you